# Equivalent of ASP.NET master pages when using just html, css and javascript

Tags: html, master-pages

I've ditched ASP.NET forms and started developing with just HTML, CSS and Javascript (JQuery, Angular). I communicate with IIS hosted Web Services to send and retrieve data to build my pages which are typically SPAs.
The thing is, all of my pages should have the same hearder, footer, etc... The master page was ideal for this.

Is there a way to do this using just HTML, CSS and JS?

Answer (score 2):

There's no *good* client side technology for this, although [frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame) and [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame) + [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) try.

The best approach is, usually, still to deliver the complete pages from the server. Either by using a server side technology (such as the ASP.NET masterpages you have abandoned) or by compiling templates at build time (e.g. with [ttree](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) or [assemble](http://assemble.io/)) before uploading the resulting static files to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a partial folder and inside that just create the html file and import it in all the files where you want to use it.

For eg: I have a **index.html** page

Now I want to add common **header** and **footer** in index.html ,so we can create a folder of partial and inside that we can create files like **header.html** and **footer.html** and write the code in both the files.
And now just **import/include** that file in whatever file you want to use it as a common components.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps static headers and footer from jQueryMobile could help.  Take a look for this link.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/toolbar/